# Netbeans no longer automatically updates my Grails running app

Tags: java, grails, netbeans-7

I'm developing a Grails (2.5.6) App, using NetBeans 7.2, and Java 7.

Everything has been fine, but recently I have noticed that if I run the app from within NetBeans, and then make a change to the code, I now have to stop the app and then re-run it again.  It used to just compile the new bits on the fly and I could test out any changes without having to stop the app and then re-run it again.

I did upgrade from Grails 2.1.1 to 2.5.6 a little while ago, but this problem (I am sure) has only been happening the last few days.  I've even uninstalled and reinstalled netbeans, but its still happening.

Very frustrating as it's really slowing me down now.

Comment: There is and have been some hot-reloading problems in atleast in the `2.5.x` branch. Controllers and Views are hot-reloaded 100% of the time but Services and Taglibs seems to have problems, also Command Objects. Which environment you are using when running the app?

Comment: Ah, that sounds interesting. I'm developing on a Win10 pro (10.0.16299 Build 10) PC, running Netbeans 7.2 (Build 201207171143), with Java 1.7.0_80 (64 Bit) and Grails 2.5.6.

Comment: No, the grails environment (dev, test, prod etc)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Dev.

Comment: In development environment hot reloading is on by default, however you will run into some entities which wont work, those that I listed above.

Comment: Thanks for that. Out of interest do you know how reloading is switched off (and presumably back on again)?  If it is on by default in the development environment, I *may* have inadvertently hit a key sequence at some point to switch it off, and if so, I may be able to switch it back on again.

Comment: No, for what I know is that you can only switch it on and off for views (gsp) with startup flags `grails -Dgrails.env=development -Dgrails.reload.enabled=true run-app`. Would be good to make a little manual testing of which entities won't hot-reload for you and which ones do.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally random, but I have solved the problem. The thing is, it had been working for years, but then suddenly last week it stopped working.

The reason? Well, last week I tidied up my disk and moved/renamed some files, and in doing so I introduced a folder which had a space in it's name. (ie all my projects used to be in a folder called \apps\grails\ and then after I tidied things up I had folders like \apps\grails 2.1.1\ and \apps\grails 2.5.6\ etc.  Note therefore, I had introduced spaces in the folder names.

As soon as I removed the spaces (so instead, I had \apps\grails2.5.6) - bingo! It started working again.

I have absolutely no idea why this should be, but it is what it is.